# Role-based authorization with ASP.NET Core 5.0

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, authorization, role-based

I can't define my Admin, Company, Agency roles because

```
services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>()
        .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

is not working or is not defining and it gives me an error

```
Error   CS1061  'IServiceCollection' does not contain a definition for 'AddDefaultIdentity' and no accessible extension method 'AddDefaultIdentity' accepting a first argument of type 'IServiceCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Here is my ConfigureServices method:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc();
    services.AddControllersWithViews();
    services.AddDbContext<TradeTurkDBContext>();
    services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>()
            .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<TradeTurkDBContext>();

    services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddCookie(x =>
            {
                ...
            });
    services.AddMvc(config =>
        {
            ...
        });
}
```

And here is my using libraries

```
using BL.TradeTurk;
using DAL.TradeTurk;
using Entities.TradeTurk;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using System.Security.Claims;
```

Can anyone tell me which part I am missing?

I looked at that `AddRoles` part in the Microsoft sources and there is nothing different my code and their source code.

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/aspnet/core/security/authorization/roles?view=aspnetcore-5.0) is Microsoft source down to the page.

Comment: How are you trying to define these roles?

Comment: im trying to add identity at this moment. after that i gonna create some role in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think The problem was in the order of Authentication and Authorization in the pipeline, Authentication should always be placed before Authorization. Change your middleware order in Configure method like below:-

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            else
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");

            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();
                
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
                {
                    endpoints.MapControllers();
                    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                        name: "default",
                        pattern: "{controller=Account}/{action=Login}/{id?}");
                });
}
```

Comment: my problem is not that. my problem is VisualStudio2019 is not defining my "services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>() .AddRoles<IdentityRole>() .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();"  code

Comment: ```Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI;``` add this library, I think it works.

Comment: its not even exist :(

Comment: oops, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity. UI.Services are not available for ASP.NET Core 5.0 Preview. actually, I forgot you are using 5.0 version.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio  read this article.

Comment: i know, that is why im using ```Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.``` as u can see in my library down to the question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61619369/iservicecollection-does-not-contain-a-definition-for-adddefaultidentity   Is not your answer which you want?

Answer (score 2):

I did it in .net5 with customized identity as below:

- create custom user and role:

```cs
public class AppUser : IdentityUser
{
}

public class AppRole : IdentityRole
{
}

public class AppUserRole : IdentityUserRole<string>
{
    public virtual AppUser User { get; set; }
    public virtual AppRole Role { get; set; }
}
```

- Create custom db context:

```cs
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<AppUser, AppRole, string, IdentityUserClaim<string>, AppUserRole, IdentityUserLogin<string>, IdentityRoleClaim<string>, IdentityUserToken<string>>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    } 
}
```

- Register custom db context and identity classes in startup:

```cs
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => //...);
services.AddIdentity<AppUser, AppRole>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
        .AddDefaultUI()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

- Finally define role based authorization:

```cs
services.AddAuthorization(ops =>
{
    ops.AddPolicy("RequireAdmins", policy => policy.RequireRole("Admins"));
});

services.AddRazorPages()
        .AddRazorPagesOptions(ops =>
        {
                ops.Conventions.AuthorizeFolder("/", "RequireAdmins");
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using
services.AddIdentityCore().AddRoles();

Comment: its not defining that part ```services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>()``` .it says "IServiceCollection does not contain a defination 'AddDefaultIdentity'"......