# 'IServiceCollection' does not contain a definition for 'AddDefaultIdentity' and no accessible extension method in Asp.Net Core Identity

Tags: asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-identity

I apply this line in Startup.cs in asp.net Core 6.0.

```
services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options =>
        {
```

Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Error CS1061 'IServiceCollection' does not contain a definition for 'AddDefaultIdentity' and no accessible extension method 'AddDefaultIdentity' accepting a first argument of type 'IServiceCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) AdminProject D:\ECommerceProject\AdminProject\Startup.cs 19 Active

```
dotnet add package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
dotnet add package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore
```

These are files are included on .csproj.

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="6.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="6.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="6.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

And asp.net core 6.0 version i have.

Comment: Have you tried this answe -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61619369/iservicecollection-does-not-contain-a-definition-for-adddefaultidentity?rq=2

Comment: Does this answer your question? [IServiceCollection does not contain a definition for AddDefaultIdentity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61619369/iservicecollection-does-not-contain-a-definition-for-adddefaultidentity)